# ASP.NET MVC get current host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I get the host without using `Request`? This code can be placed in a controller:

```
return String.Equals(this.Request.Url.Host, absoluteUri.Host, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

but I'm moving it out of a controller and need to find another way to replace this `this.Request.Url.Host`.

My whole purpose is to have access to this method in a helper class:

```
Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl);
```

My helper method will look like this:

```
public static string GetLocalUrl(string url)
{
     if(Url.IsLocalUrl()){
         return url;
     }
     else{
         return Action("Security", "Home");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use  `HttpContext.Current.Request`, or inject an instance of `HttpContextBase` into whatever it is that needs this information. I would recommend option 2 because, you can then easily test this other component. Since HttpContextBase can be mocked/stubbed.

Comment: But, how to be when I get an exception:
`System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context`
?

Answer (score 19):

You can use this outside of a controller:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

Comment: This did the trick in a MVC5 project. Since this code was is in a controller its probably safe to assume there will always be a viable context to pull from.

Answer (score 3):

In the html helper you can use

```
    htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url
```